# Why has my server stopped working since I've updated it to 1.7.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My server's been having a lot of problems in **1.6.4**.

When I finally figured out what the problem was, I fixed my server.

That was a day before **1.7.2** came out. When **1.7.2** came out, I updated my vanilla server to **1.7.2** and still no one, but me (localhost) can get on.

I've:

- Checked my firewall settings,
- Re-portforwarded,
- Tried the .exe AND .jar server files they have on minecraft.net.

What's the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try deleting and recreating the firewall rule.

Comment: @Lumberjack May have it right. If you can connect locally, your server hasn't stopped *working*, just your networking setup has. Your firewall may no longer recognise this server as the same program, if it's using a triggered forwarding rule.

Comment: What error message are people getting when they try to connect?

Comment: the error message that people are getting is: 
Failed to connect to the server
java.net.ConnectException:Connection timed out: no further information

Comment: I tried what Lumberjack suggested, deleting and recreating the firewall rule. I didn't work... Thanks for trying to help tho

Comment: @Omnikron Are you using more than one Firewalls? That could be the issue. Also, it may be (this is just speculation) that the new rule you made still used the old program. See if you can find a different one that looks the same (and thus may be the new one) and try with that. Otherwise, just turn off all anti-malware/virus/etc stuff for 10mins and see if it works.